# Practical difference between rem and em units

Tags: html, css

Why would you use one over the over? I know there are resources explaining the 'difference' but what is a practical example where rem would be preferable to use over em? And visa versa.

Comment: Could you really not find a suitable resource on Google? try [this](https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/)

Comment: sorry my original question was too broad, im looking for examples where one or the other would be preferable. Right now I code everything in rems, is it important that I ever use ems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While *em* is relative to the font-size of its direct or nearest parent,
>   *rem* is only relative to the html (root) font-size.

This is the most detailed explanation I could find on this topic. https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS Values and Units Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths) specification makes it clear:

> *em* : Equal to the computed value of the ‘font-size’ property of the element on which it is used.
>
> *rem* : Equal to the computed value of ‘font-size’ on the root element. When specified on the ‘font-size’ property of the root element, the ‘rem’ units refer to the property's initial value.