# the difference between em-calc and rem-calc

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I've been using `em-calc` for CSS size definitions in my Zurb Foundation projects so far. However, recently I've noticed developers using  `rem-calc` more and more.

I know what each function does, but I don't really understand when I should use `em-calc` or `rem-calc`.

What is the difference between these two functions?

Comment: Looks like they are basically trying to do the same thing they did with `em` units but with `rem` instead now. See why you would maybe want to use `REM` over `EM` and maybe that will help clarify things. https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/

Answer (score 8):

Well in fact your question is some kind of duplicate of [How does rem differ from em in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941275/rem-in-css-in-what-way-it-differs-from-em?s=10|1.3319) (and [Practical difference between rem and em units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540219/practical-difference-between-rem-and-em-units)) and so on

`em-calc()` returns the em value of your input in pixels, whilst 
`rem-calc()` returns rem units. In practice that means that when you use `rem-calc()` to set the font-size of a selector the font size is relative to the font size of the `html` attribute instead of its direct parent.

You can see the diffence in the following example:

**html**

```
<body>
<section> section text
    <small>small text</small>
</section>   

<section class="rem"> section .rem text
    <small>small text</small>
</section>
</body>
```

**sccs**

```
section {
font-size: em-calc(24);
small { font-size: em-calc(12); }
}

section.rem {
font-size: rem-calc(24);
small { font-size: rem-calc(12); }
}
```

The result of the above will look like that shown in the image below:

[image]

Now change the font size of the `section` tags:

```
section {
font-size: em-calc(48);
small { font-size: em-calc(12); }
}

section.rem {
font-size: rem-calc(48);
small { font-size: rem-calc(12); }
}
```

Notice that because of both `section` tags are direct parents of the `body` using `rem-calc(48)` or `rem-calc(48)` for the font-size of the `section` in the above wont make any difference for this example.

Now the result will look like as follows:
[image]

As you can see, the font size for the small does not scale with its parent.

Personally i think you should use `rem-calc()` for the main structure elements of your page (header, footer, content, navigation etc.) and `em-calc()` for the element nested in the preceding main elements.

So for the example use here:

```
section {
font-size: rem-calc(20);
small { font-size: em-calc(10); }
}
```